# Conditional formatting in Excel no numerical values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have watched a few youtube tutorials, but I can't seem to find one for exactly what I would like to do so thought I would post on here!

I have an excel document with the results of a genomics experiment (I am looking for which genes are present or absent in certain bacterial groups). I have 29 columns and they each belong to one of four distinct groups. The information below each column is either filled in with a particular unique code if the gene is present or left blank if it is absent, but each code is a mixture of letters and numbers and is unique to each column. So, I would like to set the conditional formatting based on the cells being filled in or blank. I would like to make the cell green if the cell is filled in (meaning the gene is present) between all four groups, red if it is only present in one of the groups and then something like yellow if it shared between Group 1 (data in columns O-Y) and 2 (Z-AI), orange if between 1 (O-Y) and 3 (AJ-AM), dark orange if between 2 (Z-AI) and 3 (AJ-AM) and left white if it is shared between any of the groups and group 4 (AN-AQ).

Unsure if it is possible or if the above makes sense but would appreciate any tips/tutorial links/help! [The first image is of the four groups and as you can see they are all filled in because all the groups share these genes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQdjD.png)
[Then we start to see some gaps as the genes are not shared between all the groups anymore, the slight issue is that not all of the members in the group will have all of the same genes but even if one of the members has it, I would need it to be conditionally formatted according to the rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Oaz.png)
Sorry, I couldn't copy over the table as text from the website you suggested, but hope these screenshots are useful!

[This is where I am up to, the different colours are there but not in the right cells as some of the blank cells have been coloured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJZ37.png)

Comment: Could you give us some idea of how many rows of data there are? I imagine not every column will have the same number of rows (reason for asking is that it could get slow and unresponsive if there are say 100K rows). Ideally, some sample data (even just a few rows) is always useful to get a picture of it. I guess also, if gene present in groups 2,3 and 4 say, would that be dark orange or white?

Comment: Hi Tom! I have about 5000 rows, all of the columns have the same number of rows as there are about 5000 genes that we are looking for but some of them are blank if the gene isn't present. Happy to send you a picture of the layout if that helps, I may have to blank out the gene name column as I am working on this data for a publication, if that's OK?

Comment: Paste it into your question if you can - either as an image (cropping out gene name column or substituting some made-up data) or better as text (websites like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ are useful to format it). The question is a bit easier than I imagined, or at least involves less processing, because I hadn't appreciated that the same gene was always in the same row for every column.

Comment: @TomSharpe thank you! I have added the screenshots now!

Comment: Thanks! It's still pretty tough to understand coming to it cold, but my understanding so far is that the data gets increasingly sparse as you go down but if _something_ is filled in in columns O-Y and _something else_ is filled in in columns Z-AI for any row, the cells that are filled in should be coloured yellow, for instance? All the data in the screen shot should be green?

Comment: Hi Tom, yes that is correct! I appreciate the data is difficult to understand without all of the context but you're right! If like in the first screenshot, all of the groups have something in that row, then all of the cells in that row should be green. If like you say there is something in O-Y and in Z-AI in that row the cells in that row should be yellow. The colouring rule should colour each row depending on the column as each row will have a different combination of cells filled in or blank bc one gene may be present in all the groups but the next gene only present for one group etc.

Comment: Great. I will draft a partial answer just to see if it's on the right lines.

Comment: Thank you so much. As I have just said to the other person helping to answer this, maybe it would be best to colour the column containing the gene names (1 column x 5000 rows) rather than all of the 29 columns with the data (29 columns x 5000 rows) depending on the rules set in the columns O-AQ because I've just tried to apply a rule and the sheet crashed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well massively oversimplified:

Green rule

```
=AND(O2<>"",COUNTA($Z2:$AI2)>0,COUNTA($AJ2:$AM2)>0,COUNTA($AN2:$AQ2)>0)
```

Yellow rule

```
=AND(O2<>"",COUNTA($Z2:$AI2)>0,COUNTA($AN2:$AQ2)=0)
```

Orange rule

```
=AND(O2<>"",COUNTA($AJ2:$AM2)>0,COUNTA($AN2:$AQ2)=0)
```

Red rule

```
=AND(O2<>"",$Z2:$AQ2=0)
```

(all of these are custom formulas and only applied to columns O-Y so far, starting at row 2)

[image]

Result

[image]

If this is on the right lines, it would have to be repeated in a similar way for the remaining groups of columns.

**EDIT**

So the formula for all groups would be:

Green

```
=AND(O2<>"",COUNTA($O2:$Y2)>0,COUNTA($Z2:$AI2)>0,COUNTA($AJ2:$AM2)>0,COUNTA($AN2:$AQ2)>0)
```

Yellow

```
=AND(O2<>"",COUNTA($O2:$Y2)>0,COUNTA($Z2:$AI2)>0,COUNTA($AN2:$AQ2)=0)
```

Orange

```
=AND(O2<>"",COUNTA($O2:$Y2)>0,COUNTA($AJ2:$AM2)>0,COUNTA($AN2:$AQ2)=0)
```

Red

```
=AND(O2<>"",COUNTA($O2:$Y2)>0,$Z2:$AQ2=0)
```

Dark orange

```
=AND(O2<>"",COUNTA($Z2:$AI2)>0,COUNTA($AJ2:$AM2)>0,COUNTA($AN2:$AQ2)=0)
```

[image]

[image]

**Note**

If some cells in each of groups 1, 2 and 3 were filled in, the fill colour would depend on the order of the rules (because yellow, orange or dark orange could all be triggered).

Comment: That has worked Tom! But only for columns O-Y up to row 6. What would I need to do to apply to the full document? Just change the applies to box? And how would I go about making the red rule? I have added a screenshot to show what has happened, as the rules haven't worked properly, any thoughts?

Comment: I've put the red rule in. You can apply the rules to all the rows and it should still work. If it's important to highlight individual cells like I've tried to do, unfortunately you do have to do another four rules for each of the other three groups of columns. It's not quite just a case of changing the 'applies to', for example the red rule for group 2 would be =and(z2<>"",counta($o2:$z2)=0,counta($aj2:$Aq2)=0). On the other hand, you could do like @Norie and just apply conditional formatting to column A, which would be a lot less work.

Comment: Thank you so much, it has all worked and I have managed to apply it to the whole sheet. You are a life saver!! I would like to change just one thing to make it perfect. The Red rule, is it possible to make it red only if it is present in group 1 and in none of the other groups? Thank you again!!

Comment: That's great! Not sure about the last point - if you only apply the red rule to columns O-Y as in my answer (not in the comment), it will only flag up cells that are filled in in columns O-Y and nowhere else, so I don't think you need to do anything else for that rule other than remove it from the other groups?

Comment: Have completed the rules so you can compare them with yours, and added an alternative red rule that extends across all columns plus a dark orange one that in fact looks brown (colour vision not great I'm afraid)

Comment: You have been so so helpful! I have applied it now and the formatting is working! It is not perfect yet as sometimes it flags up when some cells in group 2 are filled in but I will keep playing around with it and hopefully I can get it to work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For your first condition you can go the conditional formatting and select a new rule. Here you want to "use a formula to determine which cells to format":

For the green condition use: `=NOT(ISBLANK(A1))`

For your other conditions if I understand this correctly you are changing the colors on the columns. Then you could apply this rule, as a new rule with a different color and only set it for the columns of that group. You would need to change A1 with the appropriate column start (O1 for example)

A quick edit, I think I initially misunderstood what you were trying to do. You can use this formula to search the other columns for content and then apply to the appropriate cell:
=IF(OR(SEARCH("O",A:A),SEARCH("p",A:A)), 1, 0)=1 - this will let you ask the formula to see specific genes in a particular column

Comment: Hi, thank you! I would love to try this but when I click on conditional formatting and new rule it prompts me to insert numerical minimum and maximum values. I am on Excel on a Mac. Is there a different way to create rules on Mac? Sorry if this is a silly question!

Comment: Hi Try this:
On the Home tab, click Conditional Formatting > New Rule

In the Style box, click Classic

Under the Classic box, click to select Format only top or bottom ranked values, and change it to Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

Comment: I have tried that but the document crashes as it is such a large number of cells to apply that rule to (29 columns x 5000 rows). How about instead of each the cells under the 29 columns getting coloured, it is the gene names which are in column A (1 column x 5000 rows), depending on the rules set on columns O-AI, if that makes sense?

Comment: yes you could do this with an hlookup; assuming A1 is the column you are transcribing
=hlookup(A1, A:ZZ, 1, True); here A1 is what you are looking up, A:ZZ is your table range, so this would extend as far as necessary, 1 is the return value, from your example it would pull the group header. In this case I would not merge them, and True would be an approximate match for the gene, you may want to play with this parameter a little.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the conditional formatting like it is in this image.[image: Conditional formatting rules]

### All groups

COUNTA($O2:$Y2)*COUNTA($Z2:$AI2)*COUNTA($AJ2:$AM2)*COUNTA($AN2:$AQ2)

### Groups 2 & 3

COUNTA($Z2:$AI2)*COUNTA($AJ2:$AM2)

### Groups 1 & 2

COUNTA($O2:$Y2)*COUNTA($Z2:$AI2)

### Groups 1 & 3

COUNTA($O2:$Y2)*COUNTA($AJ2:$AM2)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am having some issues with copying the formula as they keep changing when I attempt to scroll through it using the arrows. Would it be possible to copy and paste the formulas into a comment please?

Comment: I'll add the formulas to the answer.

Comment: Sorry! These formulas haven't worked. Do I need to add =AND(O2<>"" at the beginning like in Tom's formulas?

Comment: How did they not work? Which range did you apply them to? They are meant to be applied to column A rather than the whole sheet?

Comment: I applied them to column $A$2:$A$5 but the formatting doesn't apply, any thoughts why? Ideally I would apply it to column 1 instead of the whole sheet so this would be perfect!

Comment: If you also had any ideas how to make the red rule only red if the row is unique to group 1, that would be great!